# How to make a filter in a Spinner?

Tags: android-widget

I have in my application a spinner, with more than 1000 product names, I would like when the user types any letter the spinner analysis shows the products that begin with that letter. Any idea how to do this? or any other suggestions? ...
Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `TextView` to the layout, add a `TextWatcher` and then filter the `Spinner` based